# Accept block that reads/assigns instance variables

Tags: ruby

Consider this:

```
class Foo
  def secret
    @some_ivar
  end    
end

foo_instance = Foo.new

foo_instance.in_foos_context do
  @some_ivar = "bar"
end

foo_instance.secret
=> "bar"
```

Aside from looking dubious, is this possible? If so, how do I implement the `in_foos_context` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `instance_eval`

```
class Foo
  def secret
    @some_ivar
  end    

  def in_foos_context(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end
end

foo_instance = Foo.new

foo_instance.in_foos_context do
  @some_ivar = "bar"
end

foo_instance.secret # => "bar"
```

Comment: I feel lucky today :)

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
foo_instance.instance_variable_set '@some_ivar', 'bar'
foo_instance.secret
=> "bar"
```

The combo `#instance_variables`,`#instance_variable_get` and `#instance_variable_set` are meant for this.

Comment: I don't like this notation, which is why I am curious if a nicer looking implementation exists. Furthermore, the other suggestions allows me to execute the block in the context of other objects as well at a future time, where as instance_variable_set does not.

Comment: That depends on what you want. BTW, no implementation is needed. `instance eval` is defined on `BasicObject`. So you can do `whatever_object.instance_eval`.

Comment: This might not be the most versatile solution, but the question did not put a premium on versatility.  To merely set an instance variable--what was requested--I don't think one need look beyond `instance_variable_set`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do as below :

```
class Foo
  def secret
    @some_ivar
  end
  def in_foos_context(arg,&block)
    instance_exec(arg,&block)
  end    
end

foo_instance = Foo.new

foo_instance.in_foos_context("bar") do |v|
  @some_ivar = v
end

foo_instance.secret
# => "bar"
```

Comment: Is it better than `instance_eval`?